# How can I use Provider for async data? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, provider, sqflite

## Background

I am building super simple TODO list app for practicing Flutter. If you input a string and click "add", then the text is shown in the list on the upper part.

## Question

When and how should I call `model.getTasks()` (= update data asynchronously) and `model.refresh()` (= `notifyListeners`)?

I find the list is not updated immediately because I don't use `await` for `model.getTasks()`. I tried these but I would like to know if there are better ways.

- Use `await model.getTasks()` and make `build` an async function. --> Compile error
- Add `await model.getTasks()` right before `model.refresh()`. --> `model.tasks` is not updated before rendering `ListView` when opening the app. `model.getTasks()` are called twice when creating new tasks.

## Screenshot

[image: App TODO list page]

## Code details

- `model.tasks` is `List<Task>`, which is to store tasks fetched from DB (`sqflite`).
- `model.getTasks()` is an async function to fetch data from DB and overwrite `model.tasks`.
- `model.refresh()` is only for calling `notifyListeners()`.
- `TodoListPage` is the listener of the model's `notifyListeners`.

```
class TodoListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('TodoListPage.build');
    final model = Provider.of<TodoListModel>(context);
    model.getTasks();

    Future createTask() async {
      TaskData taskData = await DatabaseHandler()
          .insertTask(new TaskData(name: _textFieldController.text));
      model.refresh();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'TODO List',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 150,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text(model.tasks[index].name);
              },
              itemCount: model.tasks.length,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Add',
          ),
          Form(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _textFieldController,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('onPressed');
                    print(_textFieldController.text);
                    createTask();
                  },
                  child: Text('New'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `FutureBuilder` inside a `StatefulWidget` :

```
class TodoListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override 
  _TodoListPageState createState() => _TodoListPageState();
}

class _TodoListPageState extends State<TodoListPage> {
  TodoListModel model;
  Future<List<Tasks>> _getTasks;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    model = Provider.of<TodoListModel>(context);
    _getTasks = model.getTasks();
  }

  @override
  Widget build() {
    FutureBuilder<List<Tasks>>(
      future: _getTasks,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return Text("Loading tasks...");
        }

        final tasks = snapshot.data;

        // ...
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And in your model :

```
Future<List<Tasks>> getTasks() async {
  if (tasks == null) {
    tasks = await loadFromDatabase();
  }

  return tasks;
}
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to use both `StatefulWidget` and `Provider`? I thought both were for managing states, so I would be better if I could choose only one of them.

Comment: It's totally fine, you can check the documentation : https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 1):

when you set the `ChangeNotifierProvider`, it calls in the `TodoListModel()`
only one time `refreshTasks()`
that's similar to your model.getTastks() in the Widget build()

then i place a Consumer as deep in the Widget tree as possible
and this Consumer gets everytime newbuild when i Press the RaiseButton or on `notifyListeners();`

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class TodoList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TodoListModel()),
      ],
    child: TodoListPage()
    );
  }
}


class TodoListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('TodoListPage.build');

    // listen: false, if the provider sends e notify, this part is not refreshing
    final model = Provider.of<TodoListModel>(context, listen: false);

    // i place this future in the TodoListModel Class
    /*Future createTask() async {
      //TaskData taskData = await DatabaseHandler().insertTask(new TaskData(name: _textFieldController.text));

      model.refreshTasks();
    }*/

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'TODO List',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 150,
            child: new Consumer<TodoListModel>(
                builder: (context, prov2, child) {

                  // this part is updating every notifyListeners
                  //      it's better when you place the consumer,as deep as possible in the widget tree
                  print("Consumer build");

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Text(model.tasks[index].name);
                    },
                    itemCount: model.tasks.length,
                  );
                },
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Add',
          ),
          Form(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _textFieldController,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('onPressed');
                    //print(_textFieldController.text);
                    //createTask();
                    model.createTask(new TaskData(name: _textFieldController.text));
                  },
                  child: Text('New'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskData {
  final String name;

  TaskData({this.name});
}

class TodoListModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  // this Function only calls when the Provider is set at ChangeNotifierProvider like initTodoListModel
  TodoListModel () {
    print("TodoListModel Class");

    refreshTasks();
  }

  // define TaskData, with getter
  List<TaskData> _tasks = [new TaskData(name: "test"), new TaskData(name: "test2")];
  List<TaskData> get tasks => _tasks;

  // getTasks async
  Future refreshTasks() async {

    // fetch something in the Database
    // _tasks = await await DatabaseHandler().getTasks();

    notifyListeners();

  }

  Future createTask(TaskData newTask) async {

    // add Task with DatabseHandler, or in this example a simple list.add
    _tasks.add(newTask);

    //refreshing with notifyListeners
    refreshTasks();
  }

}
```

Comment: In TodoListModel class, `Future createTask(TaskData newTask) { } `  you missed to insert new task - db insert as mentioned in TodoListPage. :-|

      //TaskData taskData = await DatabaseHandler().insertTask(new TaskData(name: _textFieldController.text));